# What does "real" in pseudocode indicate?

Tags: python, pseudocode

I'm trying to translate this pseudocode and can't do it accurately. In particular, I can't seem to figure out what `real` here means. This is the pseudocode:

```
Function Real average(Real values[], Integer size)
    Declare Real total = 0.0
    Declare Integer counter = 0

    While counter < size
        Set total = total + values[counter]
        Set counter = counter + 1
    End While

    Return total / size
End Function

Declare Real scores[6] = 90, 80, 70, 100, 60, 80
Display average(scores, 6)
```

And this is what I've come up with:

```
def average(values[], int(size))
    total = 0.0
    counter = 0

    while counter < size:
        total = total + values[counter]
        counter = counter + 1

    return total / size

scores[6] = 90, 80, 70, 100, 60, 80
print(average(scores, 6))
```

Comment: A ["real" number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)? Or for a computer possibly a [floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)? (For computers those are usually equivalent)

Comment: I assumed as much, but I suppose my syntax is still incorrect

Comment: I suggest you [read the very excellent Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/), as you make some very basic mistakes. Remember: Python is a dynamically typed language, where you don't declare variables with a certain type or arity.

Comment: You don't need an "algorithm" for this, it's just `sum(values)/len(values)`

Comment: The use of `Real` may hark back to when [Pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Real) was the Learning to Program language of choice.

Comment: The language ALGOL also used `real` as the name of its floating-point type, and for a while was used as the standard algorithmic description language. Later, the various styles of pseudocode could, I believe, be described as *ad hoc* dialects of ALGOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages use the term "real" in place of "float" etc.  Therefore, in Python, with this bit of code you can leave it out. 
..but there are a few things wrong with your code other than that. For example you just want

```
scores=[90,80, 70, 100, 60, 80]
```

then just give average "scores" and 6

Like this

```
def average(values ,size):
    total = 0.0
    counter = 0

    while counter < size:
        total = total + values[counter]
        counter = counter + 1

   return total / size

scores = [90, 80, 70, 100, 60, 80]
print(average(scores, 6))
```

Whilst clearly it is not necessary to do this in this way, I presume you are just learning Python...